# Define method as Transient in Jersey-Guice

Tags: java, guice, jersey-2.0

I have a POJO class and I want to make some of it's getters Transient. Is it possible to do this using Jersey-Guice? If not - what other JSON library could you recommend instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Neither Jersey nor Guice are JSON libraries. Please clarify your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with JSON in Java, I would recommend to use the new **JSR 353 JSON Processing**. Here is the reference implementation [documentation](https://jsonp.java.net/).